# Create a graph from a two column resultset

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010, union

I need to create a sql query to analyze the atendimetos employee

My goal with this query and create a graph showing the total minutes called : how many were up 120minutes (very service time ) and
how many were below 120minutes ( normal calls ) put to use in the chart in C#

The easiest way would be to result in two columns am I right?

How can I do that ? I am unable to think of a solution.

```
SELECT SUM(CallDuration)
FROM CallsFromCustomers
WHERE  DATE(CallDate) Between'2015-06-01' And '2015-06-31'
AND CallDuration < 120
UNION 
SELECT
SUM(CallDuration)
FROM CallsFromCustomers
WHERE  DATE(CallDate) Between '2015-06-01' And '2015-06-31'
AND CallDuration >= 120
```

Result

```
SUM(CallDuration)|
            5584 |
            759  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CallsFromCustomers
WHERE  DATE(CallDate) Between'2015-06-01' And '2015-06-31'
AND CallDuration < 120) AS ShortCalls, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CallsFromCustomers
WHERE  DATE(CallDate) Between '2015-06-01' And '2015-06-31'
AND CallDuration >= 120) AS LongCalls
```

Comment: I will correct the statement , I'm sorry need total minutes , my doubts and to generate the graph easily in C # and must have two columns (one with so-called up / normal calls ) am I right ?

Comment: But the query presented in the question already seems to do this. Is it not working or what?

Comment: Yes it works, just wanted to know if this correct by i need to use on a chart and there is a column as I will present the chart series will if there is only one column ?

Comment: Oh you want the two cells to be on the same line?

Comment: My idea was to get the result :                                                                                                                    
|Above 120 minutes | normal calls |

Comment: that way my chart will be created perfectly